# Jquery Validations not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use Jquery validations on a form that uses two datepicker "effectiveDate" and "termDate". EffectiveDate must not be prior to TermDate. The datepicker works but there are not any errors being display when I violate the validation.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").validate();
        var term = $("#TermDate").val();
        $("#EffectiveDate").datepicker({
            minDate: term
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How are you configuring jQuery Validate? I don't see any rules specified.

Comment: I guess not. I was under the impression that it would understand minDate. From what I saw at http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a validation rule (`dpDate`) as explained in [this article](http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").validate({
        rules: {
            // EffectiveDate is the name of the input, not the id
            // so make sure that the input is defined like this:
            // <input type="text" id="EffectiveDate" name="EffectiveDate" />
            EffectiveDate: {
                required: true,
                dpDate: true
            }
        }
    });

    var term = $("#TermDate").val();
    $("#EffectiveDate").datepicker({
        minDate: term
    });
});
```

For this rule to take effect you must add the `jquery.ui.datepicker.validation.js` extension to your page.